# TensorFlow linear regression tutorial gets error when running in TensorFlow GPU (it's OK when running in CPU environment)

Tags: python, windows, numpy, tensorflow, gpu

I am just starting to learn Tensorflow.

I install 02 environments for tensorflow on my Windows machine, one for GPU and one for CPU (following guides in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).

Then, I try the simple linear regression tutorial in this link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started
==> "tf.contrib.learn" section ==> "Basic Usage"

When running under CPU environment, it is OK.
Outputs are {'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 1.4467682e-07}

But when I run the program under GPU environment, below error occured:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>   C:\Users\LiemLD\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py in ()
>        15 try:
>   ---> 16     from . import multiarray
>        17 except ImportError:
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

....

> ImportError: 
>   Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
>   likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
>   If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
>   files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Comment: Did you try what the `ImportError` message suggested?

Comment: No, I did not follow the message. I reinstalled Python3 from https://www.python.org, then reinstalled numpy from pip. It works.